# numpy array value error

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to load a group of .jpg images as the training data set for tensorflow on my Macbook, the code I used is copied as below:

```
def load_data(dir_name, size=None, ext='.jpg'):
    images = []
    labels = []
    for ln in os.listdir(dir_name):
        new_dir_name = os.path.join(dir_name, ln)
        for fn in os.listdir(new_dir_name):
            if fn.endswith(ext):
                fd = os.path.join(new_dir_name, fn)
                images.append(load_image(fd, size))
                labels.append(load_label(new_dir_name))
    return {'images':np.vstack(np.array(images, dtype=np.float32)), 'labels':np.vstack(np.array(labels, dtype=np.float32))}
```

It turned to trigger a ValueError which showed as below:

```
line 11, in load_data
return {'images':np.vstack(np.array(images, dtype=np.float32)), 'labels':np.vstack(np.array(labels, dtype=np.float32))}
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What do `load_image` and `load_label` return? `list`s? `numpy` arrays?

Comment: They both return an array.

Comment: Are each of images and labels all the same dimension?